# Open a window behind the current window using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a window on click, but I want to open it behind the current window, or when the new window opens it should minimize itself. I have made a function but it actually did not work.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function wn(){
  var mm=window.open('http://www.google.com','newwindow','width=200, height=200', "_blank");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="wn()">click</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds dangerously like those on-click, annoying, popup ads...

Comment: Google "popunder." Basically you do window.open followed by window.focus.

Comment: Just a note - most browsers won't even open this window :)

Comment: is edited answer work for you ???

Comment: i just forgot to include child window code can you please include that code in you child window and check it out ...this will work for you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Parent window HTML**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function openPopUP() {
  window.open('mywindow.html','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=350,height=135')
}
</script>

<body onLoad="openPopUP();">
or
<a href="javascript:openPopUP();">Click to open popup</a>
```

**Child Window i.e PopUp Window File**

The below script should be in the child window. The child window will open and will automatically be hidden after 1 second. The value `1000` specified in the `setTimeout` method is the duration in milliseconds for which the child window will be open. You can increase this timeout duration if you want the child window to be open longer.

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);" 
          onFocus="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);">
```

---

This might work for you: Add this line of code in the `onload` event of your child window...

```
window.parent.opener.focus();
```

Comment: no it is not working. popup open and it still infront of parent window

Comment: @amit - its popup the window and hide in 1 sec that normal nature thats how it works...there might not be other way to do this..

Comment: may be i am doing something wrong. i have put my code in jsfiddle can u pls have look

Comment: @amit- i just forgot to include child window code can you please include that code in you child window and check it out ...this will work for you

Comment: If we don't have any control in child window, how can we hide the popupwindow behind the parent window?

Answer (score 13):

```
popunder = window.open('http://www.google.com','newwindow','width=200, height=200', "_blank");
popunder.blur();
window.focus();
```

Comment: Not sure if browsers have wised up to this technique, but this does NOT work in either FF or Chrome these days. Popup stays in front.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this.

```
window.open(url); 
self.focus();
```

Answer (score 5):

Although it causes security issues, but I guess one of the way to do it is :

```
popup = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'newwindow',  "_blank");
popup.blur();
```

This will work only in IE. For other browsers you need to set the security level to minimum.

Answer (score 3):

```
popunder = window.open('your_site_url','newwindow','width=500, height=500', "_blank");
popunder.blur();
window.focus();
```

or simply

```
window.open(url); self.focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want real popunder capabilities there is a great jQuery plugin to handle it at https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder

It uses a combination of various techniques to accomplish it across various browsers. Not all browsers can handle it the same but the results are very similar.

Current browser compatibility is listed as: <sup>(last updated April '18)</sup>

- Mozilla Firefox 3-57
- Google Chrome 10-62
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 6-11 -- MSIE 6-8 requires jquery 1.x
- Apple Safari 5

Answer (score 1):

Finally , it was working for me only in chrome browser. Add this code in Parent window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function popWindow() 
    { 
    var popupo = window.open("popup.html", 'newwindow','toolbar=no,status=no,width=650,height=450', "_blank");
    popupo.moveTo(0, 0);
    popunder.blur();
    window.focus();
    } 
</script>
```

Add this code in child window body onload event as

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);" onFocus="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);">
```

Comment: where did you set `popunder` or was that a copy/paste from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Insted of a new window, we can create an iframe and open your url in the iframe and then make the iframe display none also print the iframe content if you want.

```
var ifrmId = 1;
jQuery(document).on('click', '.myFunc', function(e) {
    var url = 'www.xyz.com';
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", url);
    ifrm.setAttribute("id", ifrmId);
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    window.frames[ifrmId].focus();
    window.frames[ifrmId].contentWindow.print();
    document.getElementById(ifrmId).style.display = "none";
    ifrmId = ifrmId + 1;

});
```