# How to keep the current tab open and load the clicked link in new tab?

Tags: jquery, html, href

The following code opens link in new tab at the same time it moves control to new tab

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit</a>
```

How to keep the current tab open and load the clicked link in new tab

Comment: possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab

Comment: I doesn't get answer from that link. read question fully

Answer (score 0):

This is called a popunder and is consider **very** bad practice.

But since you asked

Take a look at the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407153/open-a-window-behind-the-current-window-using-javascript-jquery) and see if it works for you.

Comment: There is nothing called bad practice in front of learning madness. Have to learn everything

Comment: Part of your education is to learn which practices are considered bad.